# Partial derivative of integral vs. integral of partial derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

Does the followig equation hold?

$$\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {x^2}}}\left( {\int_{t - h}^t {{x^T}\left( \tau  \right)\;W\;x\left( \tau  \right)\;d\tau } } \right)\;\mathop  = \limits^? \;\;\int_{t - h}^t {\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {x^2}}}\left( {{x^T}\left( \tau  \right)\;W\;x\left( \tau  \right)\;} \right)d\tau } $$

Comment: What do *you* think?

Comment: I think it is not true!

Comment: Differentiation and integration are linear operators. It means the above is true.